# Module 'cudnn' not found:No LuaRocks module found for cudnn

Tags: lua, conda, torch, cudnn

Installed Lua and other dependencies following the standard command on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
conda install lua=5.2 lua-science -c alexbw
```

I am getting error in the line:

```
require 'cudnn'
```

The error is:
`

```
/home/parth/miniconda3/envs/fastai-tf/bin/lua: ...h/miniconda3/envs/fastai-tf/share/lua/5.2/trepl/init.lua:384: module 'cudnn' not found:No LuaRocks module found for cudnn
    no field package.preload['cudnn']
    no file '/home/ubuntu/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/cudnn.lua'
    no file '/home/ubuntu/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/cudnn/init.lua'
    no file '/home/parth/miniconda3/envs/fastai-tf/share/lua/5.2/cudnn.lua'
    no file '/home/parth/miniconda3/envs/fastai-tf/share/lua/5.2/cudnn/init.lua'
    no file '/home/parth/miniconda3/envs/fastai-tf/lib/lua/5.2/cudnn.lua'
    no file '/home/parth/miniconda3/envs/fastai-tf/lib/lua/5.2/cudnn/init.lua'
    no file './cudnn.lua'
    no file '/home/parth/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/cudnn.lua'
    no file '/home/parth/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/cudnn/init.lua'
    no file '/home/ubuntu/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.2/cudnn.so'
    no file '/home/parth/miniconda3/envs/fastai-tf/lib/lua/5.2/cudnn.so'
    no file '/home/parth/miniconda3/envs/fastai-tf/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
    no file './cudnn.so'
    no file '/home/parth/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.2/cudnn.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    ...h/miniconda3/envs/fastai-tf/share/lua/5.2/trepl/init.lua:384: in function 'require'
    src/train.lua:6: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    ...da3/envs/fastai-tf/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:145: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

`

Tried installing `cudnn` using the command `luarocks install cudnn`, which gave the output:

```
Error: No results matching query were found.
```

How to fix this dependency issue.

Comment: Try: luarocks install --server=http://luarocks.org/dev cudnn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's also available from [the **alexbw** channel](https://anaconda.org/alexbw/lua-cudnn), so if you already installed `lua-science`, just

```
conda install -c alexbw lua-cudnn
```

If you're installing from scratch, this seems like a really specialized install, so my recommendation is

```
conda create -n lua-sci -c alexbw lua=5.2 lua-science lua-cudnn
```

that is, create a new environment for it.